# SELinux contexts for rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, centos7, selinux, rhel7

I'm setting up a Centos 7 server to serve as a webserver for rails apps (deployed with capistrano) and, after reading quite a bit on SELinux I think I understand what needs to be done, but I don't know exactly the best way to get it done.
The problem is the following:

I have all my web applications under the same directory, for which I've set (recursivelly) the context *httpd_sys_content_t* using the command:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/var/www/html(/.*)?"
```

This assures me that all files there will be readable by apache, and that was my first step regarding SELinux.

**Issue #1:** After this step, I get a permission error because apache cannot execute the *.so* scripts inside the */shared/bundle/* directory (which contains the gems of this application.
To solve this issue, I recursivelly set the context of the *shared/bundle* directory to *httpd_sys_script_exec_t*. Is this wrong? Is there a better way to handle this?

**Issue #2:** I haven't reached this step yet, but I probably won't be able to upload files to the web application without setting the context of the *public/uploads* dir to *httpd_sys_content_rw_t*, which makes sense.

My biggest question here is this: 
Will I need to set these contexts every time I deploy a new Website, to make sure its uploads directory have the *httpd_sys_content_rw_t* context, and its bundle directory has the *httpd_sys_script_exec_t* context? there must be a way to set this up permanently, and maybe more ellegantly then what I've described above, but I don't want to mess too much with these contexts without fully understanding what the consequences are.

Can someone enlighten me on what would the best setup for this situation be? Am I missing something that would make this setup much easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

everything depends of the app server you use and what domain does it run in. It looks like your app server is running under httpd_t SELinux domain which might be mod_passenger. Then you will need to change the file contexts according to what httpd_t domain requires. Very good resources are:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server.html
http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/httpd_selinux/

You are on good track, but at some point you will need to start writing your own policy. This will become problem the moment your app will require do something that httpd_t is not allowed - such as connecting to remote HTTP(S) service or open a file outside of /var/www. In this case, the correct approach is to write your own SELinux policy for your application.

I have been there several times, I maintain SELinux policy for open-source application Foreman which is deployed with Passenger by default. In passenger world things are little bit complicated because it is not possible to do clean initial transition, so you end up with passenger_t domain (ideally it should be my_awesome_app_t). Anyway here is the most important file:

https://github.com/theforeman/foreman-selinux/blob/develop/foreman.te

Writing SELinux policies is a painful process, but it can improve security of your app a lot. Also it helps you to harden your codebase. More on that in my talk here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQcYXJkwTns

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your insight mate, i'll check out the info you linked to figure out the best way to apply it to my scenario.

Comment: Due to time constraints on my side, I think I'll have to go for a faster approach.

Do you think it would be too bad for me to code a set of rules that will apply to all my rails apps and allow them to execute properly for now? Something like:

semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/(.*)?/public/uploads(/.*)?"

That will set the RW context on all uploads dir on every site I have on that server? I'd then do the same for the scripts directory.

What do you think?

Comment: That is not safest approach, you are actually allowing readwrite access to all of your application, thats exactly what SELinux tries to prevents. If you need fast approach, you can simply put your domain into permissive mode while you keep rest of your system confined (in enforcing mode). That would be semanage permissive domain_t.

Comment: With the command i presented previously, i'd only give RW access to all the uploads dirs of all the sites, not the sites itself. That was the approach I ended up taking, with 2 semanage commands i've set all the permissions I required for all websites without compromising security (only uploads directory have RW and only the scripts directory has script exec permission). 
While this might not be the perfect approach, it doesn't seem too bad security wise.

Comment: Oh yes I've missed the uploads subdir, this is safe to do yes.